# APACHE Camel : aborting route after exception processor

Tags: apache-camel

```
.onException(Exception.class)
.handled(true)
.process(processorHandler)
.to("direct:myRoute")
.end()
```

Nothing is getting executed after process method. Can someone help?. I want to execute `myRoute` after my exception is processed in processor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the step `.process(processorHandler)` temporarily. Just to check if the message arrives at the direct route.

If it works like this, you could probably use other ways to do what your processor does. For example with `setBody` etc.

The point is that a processor used in onException has some special semantics. If I remember correctly, the error is always handled and the route stops at the processor. But I am not sure about this. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The .onException(Exception.class) is to handle the exception occurred in your main route. Any exception occurred within the onException block will not be handled. if you want to handle the exception then move .process(processorHandler) step to .to("direct:myRoute") and add an onException block to handle it.